# CefSharp disable 'backspace' key from navigating back

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I'm facing the following issue:

I have a Winform (C#) which contains a CefSharp browser.
I need to prevent the user from navigating back using the "backspace" key.

I searched for solutions and I found that the way to do it is by implementing the following method (IRequestHandler):

```
bool IRequestHandler.OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, 
        IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isRedirect)
{
       if (request.TransitionType.HasFlag(TransitionType.ForwardBack))
       {
                return true;
       }
       return false;
}
```

The problem is that it simply doesn't always work.
For example, if I navigate to google.com, search something and then I click the "backspace" button - I return to the previous page.

How can I solve it  - assuming that I have no control on the web pages?

Comment: You can block the backspace key going to the control completely, but I presume that wouldn't help since you want the backspace key to work within pages?

Comment: That's right. I don't want to block the backspace key completely...since I still want the users to be able to delete (using the backspace key)...I just don't want them to navigate back..

Comment: Please provide a more detailed list of steps to reproduce your problem. example 1. Navigate to google.com 2. Type some search text 3. Press tab to focus a different control. 4. Press backspace. `click the backspace button` is also confusing, do you mean press?

Comment: Here are the steps to reproduce the issue: 1.  the ChromiumWebBrowser constructor looks like that:  test = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("http://google.com"); 2. when the form open, type anything 4.Press Enter 5. Press backspace key. The results is that you are navigated back to the previous page.

Comment: Are you using `47.0.3`? Make sure you've assigned your request handler to the browser, e.g. `browser.RequestHandler = new RequestHandler();`, add some breakpoints to get a better sense of what's going on. When I press `backspace` using `Google.com` it removes a character from the search box, so maybe your missing some steps? Also it uses `ajax` to retrieve the search results, so `OnBeforeBrowser` will never be called.

Comment: I'm using the latest version and I set the "RequestHandler" property correctly. After pressing "Enter" (step number 4) - google displays all the search results and the focus is not on the search box. Therefore, when I press the "backspace" key, I navigate backward. You said that "it uses ajax to rerieve the search results" - so indeed "OnBeforeBrowser" will never be called. So how can I overcome this? How can I prevent navigating back no matter what? Thanks.

Comment: Latest version is relative, always specify an explicit version, if I come back in two months time, the latest version will be different.. After pressing enter, `Google` still has focus for me, so I'm not sure what your doing differently. Try using https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample to test. As for the ajax part, you'll have to investigate on your own, `Google` is your friend there.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution, but I use Delphi

```
procedure TForm1.Chromium1PreKeyEvent(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; const event: PCefKeyEvent; osEvent: PMsg;
  out isKeyboardShortcut, Result: Boolean);
  begin
   if event.focus_on_editable_field=0 then
   begin
   if event.windows_key_code=vk_back then
     begin
     result:=true;
     end;
    end
    else
    begin
       result:=false;
        end;
   end;
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to prevent this is to add:
NavigationCommands.BrowseBack.InputGestures.Clear(); to your Frame constructor.But I am not sure if there is any side effect.

Comment: You've tested this with `CefSharp`? Seems an unlikely solution as it doesn't use `NavigationCommands`